# Viewport not resizing layout on mobile view

Tags: html, css, mobile

My site's layout isn't responsive so I want it to shrink my whole layout if the user is viewing on mobile devices. I'm using this viewport code `<meta name=viewport content="width=1024">` but it won't shrink my layout on mobile view. Anyone know how to fix? my site is http://www.sailormoon.xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale: 1, maximum-scale: 1">
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable = yes">
```

Comment: People are much happier if you don't use a maximum-scale of 1 without good reason. It just limits the usability.